# Need help using AsyncTask to make app run in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android programming and trying to make an app that gathers data from a database though a servlet. The app was working until I was forced to re-install Eclipse. Now I appear to be having problems retrieving data from my servlet. The app complies and runs, however no "light data" is being displayed. AsyncTask apparently might help this issue (although I did create a home page with a simple enter app button and set it as my new main activity). I'd really appreciate answers specific to my code through the use of AsyncTask, thankyou.

Code connecting to the servlet: this page should appear after entering through the home page (new main activity) button:

```
package com.example.clearlight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);*/


        setContentView(R.layout.relative);
        // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.

        /*LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        rootLayout.addView(txt);
        setContentView(rootLayout);*/


        URL url = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
        try {
            String registrationUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/SensorInfo/GetLightData?sensor=light";
            url = new URL(registrationUrl);

            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(registrationUrl);
            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // request data from server
            String result = httpclient.execute(getRequest, handler);
            Log.d("MyApp", "Data from server is "+ result);


          //Creating TextView Variable**********************************
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            //Sets the new text to TextView (runtime click event)//*******
            text1.setText("Light Data= " + result);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Light Data:" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //MESSAGE BOX
            //txtMessage.setText(String.valueOf(msg1) + "  " + String.valueOf(msg2));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clearlight"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.clearlight.HomePage"
            android:label="@string/homepage" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Moved the intent filter to HomePage -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside the catch block and verify that there is no exceptions.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand. I've added the breakpoint and it complies as normal- should I be looking for something else?

Comment: You should have said what the application displays now, because it is impossible to figure out an answer to "nothing works". I supposed that you had an exception because Android 4.0 forbids to run network operations in UI thread and you application wouldn't even run.

Answer (score 1):

For android its best to never run network requests in a Activity. When you try to make a network connection you could get into a timeout, or perhaps load a very large amount of data witch makes your code 'freeze' on that line. Activity's tend to hate waiting as the screen is non-responsive then. And android will (possibly force) close your application when that goes on for to long.

Like you mentioned, a AsyncTask is a better way to load data from a network connection. AsyncTasks work more or less like normal class with the Exception of a few details. [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) link should get you upto speed on those details.

For your error: Like Vorrtex said up above, Check if you don't fall into a error. In your catch statement add: Log.e("error",e.toString()); and check if you don't get a wall-o-red-text in your LogCat.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response- I tried adding Log.e("error",e.toString()); but I recieve an error the 'e' part on e.toString(). Apologies if this is a stupid mistake on my part catch `catch (Exception ex) {Log.e("error",e.toString());
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }`

Comment: Oh my bad! I always call my Exception e by habit, but when looking at your code I see you called it ex. change it to `Log.e("error",ex.toString());`

Comment: Ok so when I click my homepage enter button I get a black screen (not responding)- I normally get either this or the proper page but without the data. Does this mean I should go ahead with AsyncTask?

Comment: You should go ahead with the Async anyway as (like I said) you should never load network objects from inside a Activity. What I forgot to mention (and what @Sajmon did mention in his answer) is that in android 3 and above its even forbidden.

To see if your current problem really has to do with the network call:  comment the entire try catch (and all code inside of it) out and run your application, see if your screen builds then.

Comment: Yes the screen still builds (without the data as usual)

Comment: If you run your code then including all code in the try catch statement you should get a message in your LogCat then, with the tag "error" There you should be able to see what goes wrong. Anyway to make your program work I recommend to just make a async class now and see how it goes from there. I think it should fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

So generally is not recommended to perform any network connections from UI Thread. For Android < 3.0 it will work but from Android 3.0 it's fixed and not allowed(NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown).

So [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is very good choice, it's pretty good designated for purposes like this. Simply, key method of AsyncTask is [doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) that runs on background Thread(is used for log running operations also for those like yours) and represents right place to perform Internet connection.

Your code where you are communicating with Servlet you should put into this method and as result you will return response as String.

Then this String is sent into [onPostExecute(String result)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method that is invoked when doInBackground() method is finished as result of background operation and here you will update your UI(set response as content of appropriate widget). OnPostExecute() already runs on UI Thread and allow UI updates.

If you are little confused, it will be better to read some tutorial:

- [Android Background Processing with Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask -
  Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)